# Android Crashlytics Null Pointer exception, on a non null var

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

Craslitycs send a crash event of null pointer exception
`NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference`
that refers to `mutablelist.addAll(it.list)`, where it.list is an object from an api response.

When I try to check if this can be null, `(it.list != null)`, AndroidStudio suggest `Condition 'it.list != null' is always 'true'` so, why this crash? And how can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your code to this question?

Comment: Maybe the crash is not where you are looking.

Comment: You just need to check list is empty or not by using collections method is ArrayList.isNullOrEmpty()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your list is empty or not by using kotlin collections function.

Use below function

```
ArrayList.isNullOrEmpty()
```

Reference link:

[Kotlin collection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html#collection-types)

Comment: I can try it, but the list is coming from an api service, and in the model of the response list is non nullable `val list: MutableList<ListModel>`, so i don't understand why, if API return null, doesn't crash in the service?